# invoke different onClick functions in a v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a set of data that needs to be looped through but each item in that data has a different onClick event. Something along the lines like:

```
list: [
  {
    text: 'a',
    icon: 'a-icon',
    onClick: () => {
      // do stuff a
    },
  },
  {
    text: '`b`',
    icon: 'b-icon',
    onClick: () => {
      // do stuff b
    },
  },
]
```

what I initially tried to do was:

```
<div v-for="(item, i) in list" :key="i" @click="item.onClick()"></div>
```

which didn't work. The error was:

```
TypeError: item.onClick is not a function
```

Then I tried:

```
<div v-for="(item, i) in list" :key="i" @click="list[i].onClick()"></div>
```

which looks weird but works. Only I can't access `this` inside `onClick` function. I could just pass `this` to the function directly like `@click="list[i].onClick(this)"` but it look weird too.

I knonw I can write a method and do `switch` according to the index. But then I had to write the `onClick` function seperately.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm not well acquainted with vue, but can you do this: `@click="list[i].onClick.bind(this).apply()"`?
I know that someone is going to yell at me for suggesting such atrocious thing, but if it works, it works.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      list: [{
          text: 'a',
          icon: 'a-icon',
          onClick: (item) => {
            let element = document.getElementById(item.text);
            console.log(element);
            console.log("Item" + item);
            console.log("Hi")
          },
        },
        {
          text: '`b`',
          icon: 'b-icon',
          onClick: (item) => {
            console.log("Item" + item);
            console.log("Hello")
          },
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, i) in list" :key="i" :id="item.text" @click="item.onClick(item)">{{item.text}}</div>
</div>
```

It's depends on what you mean by `this`. Is `this` the HTML element you are working with, or the array element being looped.

```
<div v-for="(item, i) in list" :key="i" @click="item.onClick(item)"></div> //If `this` refers to the array element being looped
```

If `this` refers to the HTML element in that loop: You can assign an unique `id`, probably `:id="'item_list'+id"` then pass it as method parameter live above. Then select the element within the method. There's defintely a better way but till now that's what I can think of

And in addition, since you are using arrow function, it may point to its nearest parent that have `this`. Try using anonymous function if it suits your need.

Comment: `this` refers to the current Vue instance, I was trying to invoke $refs inside the function

Comment: When you declare a Vue instance globally, you know you can access the Vue instance globally via the variable name right?